# How can I combine a current value of a stream with each value of another stream in bacon.js?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, bacon.js

In my application I have a state object `state`, which is mutated by GUI elements. Each time this state is mutated, an XHR is executed to update the state server-side and current state is returned. This maps nicely to Bacon.js' streams.

Now, assuming a mutation stream `mutationEventStream`, I'm trying to update my state by combining previous state value with the event trigger:

```
Bacon.onValues(state, mutationEventStream, function(data, event) {
    dataUpdateBus.push(/* extract data from event */)
})
```

(`dataUpdateBus` contains all data updates which need to go the server. `state` is what is returned by the XHR initiated with data on the `dataUpdateBus`)

My problem is now that I need a current state value to properly update it. If I had a global variable, I'd only need new events on the `mutationEventStream`, but with streams I need to mix-in my `state` stream. With the code above I'm getting every update of `state`, i.e. with data updates it's effectively an endless loop (`dataUpdateBus.push` -> XHR -> `state` -> `dataUpdateBus.push`, etc.). And since `state` is updated more frequently than `mutationEventStream` I can't use `Bacon.zip()`.

What am I doing wrong and what can I do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to combine each new value in *mutationStream* with the current value of *state*, but you don't want to trigger updates when *state* changes (that causes a "feedback" effect). The *sampledBy* combinator allows use to do just this:

```
var stateUpdates = state.sampledBy(mutationStream, function(currentState, newEvent) {
  return currentState.updatedWith(newEvent)
}).onValue(dataUpdateBus.push)
```

The key difference to your code is that updates are only generated on new events in the *mutationStream*.

Comment: So *that's* the middle-ground between `onValues` and `zip`! Works great, just as expected from you. Thanks!